# Regex to parse string input

Tags: c#, regex

I want to use regex to parse it into groups

```
string input = @"(1,2)(3,4)";
Regex.Matches(input, @"\((\d,\d)\)");
```

The results I get is not only 1,2 and 3,4 but also spaces. Can you guys help me ?

EDIT:

I want to get 2 groups 1,2 and 3,4.

Comment: Please post the output you get as well.

Comment: Not for me..... Are you using a different input than this?

Comment: Same as Dave here. Copy-pasted your code, results were (1,2) and (3,4).

Comment: As it stands, and based on the description you have given, this works correctly. You will need to post more detail about what you expect to see, and which input has caused you the problems.

Comment: Using regexpal.com to test your example seems to work fine, ignoring spaces wherever I put them.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/kP5kU6 shows your expected result, can you show us your code after Regex.Matches? So we can see if you're not doing anything that causes extra spaces to be added?

Comment: I don't see any spaces either: http://dotnetfiddle.net/joAezm

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = @"(1,2)(3,4)";
 MatchCollection inputMatch= Regex.Matches(collegeRecord.ToString(), @"(?<=\().*?(?=\))");
```

For current string you will get two outputs:

```
inputMatch[0].Groups[0].Value;
inputMatch[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

Or

You can also try foreach loop

```
 foreach (Match match in inputMatch)
{

}
```

I have not tested this code,

My Working Example:

```
MatchCollection facilities = Regex.Matches(collegeRecord.ToString(), @"<td width=""38"">(.*?)image_tooltip");
            foreach (Match facility in facilities)
            {
                collegeDetailDH.InsertFacilityDetails(collegeDetailDH._CollegeID, facility.ToString().Replace("<td width=\"38\">", string.Empty).Replace("<span class=\"icon_", string.Empty).Replace("image_tooltip", string.Empty));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you reach them? Try this:

Example:

```
MatchCollection matchs = Regex.Matches(input, @"\((\d,\d)\)");
foreach (Match m in matchs)
{
    rtb1.Text += "\n\n" + m.Captures[0].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this pattern:

```
(\((?:\d,\d)\))+
```

`+` allows that the group is repeating and can occur one or more time.

Comment: Show us some code as well, that is how do you get value from regex match.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lookarounds.

```
string input = @"(1,2)(3,4)";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=\().*?(?=\))"))
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

If your string may have other content then digits in brackets, and you need only those with digits inside, you can use more specific regex as follows.

```
string input = @"(1,2)(3,4)";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=\()\d,\d(?=\))"))
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```